# Connecting to MySQL through network without a driver

Tags: mysql, sockets

I have a MySQL database running locally on port 3306. And I would like to connect to localhost:3306 directly and run some commands without using a driver. Is there any overview of the protocol to use in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this? http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol